# iOS 8 Custom keyboard UIScrollview isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have tried to add UISchollView in custom keyboard view but it shows view but not scrolling.
here is my code. i have also tried self.view but its not working either.

```
UIScrollView *scrollview1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
    NSInteger viewcount= 8;
    for (int i = 0; i <viewcount; i++)
    {
        CGFloat y = i * 50;
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y,50, 50)];
        view.backgroundColor = (i%2==0)?[UIColor greenColor]:[UIColor blueColor];
        [scrollview1 addSubview:view];
    }
    scrollview1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height *viewcount);
    scrollview1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    scrollview1.pagingEnabled=YES;
    [self.inputView addSubview:scrollview1];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIScrollView` will scroll if its `contentSize` is greater then its frame size. So try setting its `contentSize` property and also check if `userInteraction` is enabled or not.

Hope it will work.

Comment: problem is in this line

scrollview1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height *viewcount);

self.view.frame isn't working here for me.
thanks.